# How to sort folders first in open dialog window (gtk 3.14 file chooser)

Tags: linux, fedora, gnome, gtk

I just upgraded from fedora20 to fedora21 and now the gtk file picker sorts files and folders together. I much prefer the usual and previous behaviour of displaying folders first (and I enabled that behaviour in nautilus thanks to the option there).

Is it possible to achieve that sorting also in the gtk 3.14 file chooser? If yes, how?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ok, I found it... I had to install and run the program `dconf-editor`. Then go to **org**->**gtk**->**settings**->**file-chooser**, then activate the option `sort-directories-first`.

Comment: As of [version 3.15.1](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/commit/?id=2aa3eea781ed21a02ecdf1e3c753a1ec5694d6c8) this is accessible via the context menu.

Comment: This answer is still current as of gnome 3.24, while the nautilus-specific preference from the other answer has been removed.

Comment: As of Xubuntu 20.04, I confirm the OP, and also confirms that this solution works :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for this option for GNOME 3.14 on debian (nautilus) and couldn't find anything, and now I've stumbled upon it while digging through dconf. So, for nautilus it's
`gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences sort-directories-first true` or go to dconf under org -> gnome -> nautilus -> preferences and check sort-directories-first if you prefer the GUI ;)

Comment: I don't know how things were in 3.14, but nowadays, this is literally the first option in the Preferences GUI, no need for `gsettings` or `dconf-editor`.